# Support FACTORY_ADDRESS and INIT_CODE_HASH in different forks of UniswapV2

Tags: javascript, uniswap, typescript, constant, uniswapv2

I'm trying to parse transactions of different UniswapV2 like DEXes and have problems adding new forks of UniswapV2 to my project, such as SushiSwap, etc.

I'm using `@uniswap/v2-sdk` for transactions of UniswapV2 contracts. And there is a problem because other DEXes have their own `FACTORY_ADDRESS`-es and `INIT_CODE_HASH`-es. After checking the `v2-sdk` docs, I found that these variables are hardcoded into the library.

**Here is the question:**

How would it be possible to implement, so I could parse transactions of different DEXes using UniswapV2 SDK? Or is it better to use each SDK for a specific DEX, but if there are none? Do you know any workarounds on how to break such limitations?

*Would appreciate any help!*